# ArcGIS-Server how to create a WMS with a name different from title?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

Is it possible to create a WMS layer with ArcGIS Server that will have a name property différent of the title property. How can I do that with ArcGIS Server?

I want to have a layer in WMS like that, title different of the name property:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
  <Name>lidar_mhc</Name>
  <Title>Hauteur de canopée LiDAR (dégradé)</Title>
  <KeywordList>
  <Keyword>produit dérivé</Keyword>
  <Keyword>lidar</Keyword>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS server has online documentation https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/available-wms-service-properties.htm

> The following table lists the properties available for WMS services and a description of each:
>
> Property - Description
>
> **Name**
>
> The OGC service type. This property is automatically populated by ArcGIS Server and should not be modified.
>
> **Title**
>
> The name of the map or image service that was used to create the
>   WMS service. This property is automatically populated by ArcGIS Server
>   and should not be modified.

Obviously if you want to show your clients a WMS layer title that is different than the ArcGIS default you must use for example GeoServer or MapServer in between as a proxy.

Try with you local ESRI contact if you manage to make a feature request for making the title editable.